# File input add_field not adding field to every row

Tags: logstash

I am parsing several logfiles of different load balanced serverclusters with my logstash config and would like to add a field "log_origin" to each file's entries for the later easy filtering.

Here's my input->file config in a simple example:

```
input {
  file {
    type => "node1"
    path => "C:/Development/node1/log/*"
    add_field => [ "log_origin", "live_logs" ]
  }
  file {
    type => "node2"
    path => "C:/Development/node2/log/*"
    add_field => [ "log_origin", "live_logs" ]
  }
  file {
    type => "node3"
    path => "C:/Development/node1/log/*"
    add_field => [ "log_origin", "live_logs" ]
  }
  file {
    type => "node4"
    path => "C:/Development/node1/log/*"
    add_field => [ "log_origin", "live_logs" ]
  }
}

filter {
    grok {
        match => [
            "message","%{DATESTAMP:log_timestamp}%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:class}\]%{SPACE}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{SPACE}%{GREEDYDATA:log_message}"
        ]
    }

    date { 
        match => [ "log_timestamp",  "dd.MM.YY HH:mm:ss", "ISO8601" ]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }

    mutate {
        lowercase => ["loglevel"]
        strip     => ["loglevel"]
    }

    if "_grokparsefailure" in [tags] {
        multiline {
            pattern   => ".*"
            what      => "previous"
        }
    }

    if[fields.log_origin] == "live_logs"{
        if [type] == "node1" {
            mutate { 
                add_tag => "realsServerName1"
            }
        }
        if [type] == "node2" {
            mutate { 
                add_tag => "realsServerName2"
            }
        }
        if [type] == "node3" {
            mutate { 
                add_tag => "realsServerName3"
             }
        }
        if [type] == "node4" {
            mutate { 
                add_tag => "realsServerName4"
            }
        }
    }
}

output {
  stdout { }
  elasticsearch { embedded => true }
}
```

I would have expected logstash to add this field with the value given to every logentry it finds, but it doesn't. Maybe I am completely taking the wrong approach here?

Edit: I am not able to retrieve the logs directly from the nodes, but have to copy them over to my "server". Otherwise i would be able to just use the filepath for distinguishing different clusters...

Edit: It's working. I should have cleand my data in between. Old entries without the field added cluttered up my results.

Answer (score 7):

The add_field expects a hash. It should be

```
add_field => {
 "log_origin" => "live_logs" 
}
```